# reload form on submit with latest post data

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, reload

I have a form to post content into a database. The existing database content for the form is posted into the form as the value. enalbeing the form to show the existing database content.

On submit the database is updated and to view the  newly updated content in the form the page must be reloaded.

I have produced a reload script in javascript to reload the page on submit. The page reloads but the php content doesn't update. The page still need to be reloaded manually for the new content to show up.

This is the code for my form.

```
<form method="POST" action="">
        <input type="text" name="title" <?php echo "value=\"" .$row['title']."\">"?>
        <textarea id="editor" name="content"><?php echo $row['content']; ?></textarea>
        <input type="submit" name="save" value="Save" class="submit" onclick="reload();">
    </form>
```

Javascript

```
function reload(){
document.location.reload(true);
}
```

I have also tried

```
window.location = window.location.href;
```

Both are relaoding the page but the php isn't being refreshed.

Comment: why not ajax? And if you submit the form the page is automatically reloaded (or redirected, depending on your `action` attribute)

Comment: Yes my action is to stay on the current page. I want the php form value to update. How would I go about doing this with ajax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should first update the db with submitted value before selecting the records to display in the form value.

use `<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>` in form action.

1. mysql_query("UPDATE xyz SET title=$_request['title'],... WHERE id = 1") .

2.Then select query  mysql_query("SELECT * from xxx where id =1").

These may solve your problem of reloading to get new values.

Comment: Thanks it was just the case of switching the order of the select and update statment.

Answer (score 0):

java script excecute only on the client side. php is Server side. you need to reload the PHP.

```
<form method="POST" action="<<NAME OF YOUR PHP>>.php">
    <input type="text" name="title" <?php echo "value=\"" .$row['title']."\">"?>
    <textarea id="editor" name="content"><?php echo $row['content']; ?></textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="save" value="Save" class="submit" onclick="reload();">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason it needs to be done with ajax? If you don't need ajax it's better to handle it with php. ajax is more work and doesn't have the same rate of success as submitting a form via php, sometimes weird things happen. You can just do a redirect after saving the form:

```
header("Location: /routeToYourPage&id=".$ID,TRUE,303);
```